# How to create scope in my Rails 3 model to display all where the value = false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I recently added a new field called "Review" in a column called "Posts"

I want to display only the posts where Review = false.

I am trying to add the correct scope into my Posts model to do this.

Here's the current scope that I have.

```
  default_scope order: 'posts.created_at DESC'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.without_review
    where(review: false) # or how ever you have the boolean in your db
  end
end
```

And of course a spec

```
describe Model do
  describe "::without_review" do
    it 'loads posts without reviews' do
      no_review = Model.create(review: false)
      Model.create(review: true)

      Model.without_reivew.all.should == [no_review]
    end
  end
end
```

Just use a class method and chain scopes

Comment: What would the code for the scope be where I include the `without_review`? Do I need to combine it with the original default_scope order that I posted in the original post?

Comment: it's a class method on the model, you don't need a "named scope" to do what you want instead you can just use a method

Comment: the reason why I asked is because I included that class method into the post.rb model file and I'm still seeing posts where review=true

Comment: you have to use the method... take a look at the spec

Comment: sorry I'm a little confused. I tried to figure out how to apply the method correctly. do you mind briefly explaining it?

Comment: Class methods on `ActiveRecord::Base` subclasses *are* scopes; generally class methods are used for scopes that need arguments: ["http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a named scope:

```
scope :unreviewed, where(:review => false)
```